# Prove that convergence subsequence given by the compact inclusion $W^{1,p}(I) \subset C(\bar{I})$ convege to some function in $W^{1,p}(I)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I = (0,1)$ i.e. a bounded interval.Prove that for bounded sequence $u_k$ in  $W^{1,p}(I)$ for $p = (1,\infty]$. Exist some $u\in W^{1,p}(I)$ also.such that $u_k\to u$ in $L^\infty(I)$.

My attempt,using the Sobolev embedding theorem such that $W^{1,p}(I)\subset C(\bar{I})$ is compact inclusion.

Then we know exist subsequence of $u_{n_k} \to u$ in $L^{\infty}(I)$ such that $u\in L^{\infty}(I)\subset L^p(I)$ also.

**Now we need to find the weak derivative of $u$ in order to prove that $u\in W^{1,p}$.**

There  are three possible ideas:

1. first one is if we can prove $u'_{n_k} \to v$ in $L^p(I)$.Then we are done since it even implies that $u_{n_k}\to u$ in $W^{1,p}(I)$ (which may not be very likely to happens since we know there are only weak convergence for derivative:that is $u'_{n_k}\to u'$ weakly)
2. using the criterion that if $$|\int \varphi'udx|\le \|u\|_{L^p}\|\varphi\|_{L^{p'}}$$ then we are done. (which is given in Brezis's Sobolev space book page 206 Prop 8.3)

Maybe we can insert $u_{k_n}$ into it. then the hard part is the integral $$|\int(u_{n_k}-u)\varphi' dx |\le C\|\varphi\|_{p'} ?$$
3. If we can prove $u$ is absolute continuous,then the derivative in measure theory sense exist.

I find three of them is not very obvious,I guess may be I misinterpret something?

Comment: Maybe you can try $\{u_k\}$ regarded as a sequence of $L^p$ has a weakly convergent subsequence when $p\in(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Can we try using a standard mollifier and approximate it with smooth functions like given in section 2.4 : https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf and then it will be easy to prove this...Though as we tend from approximation to actual function there could be issues

Comment: @Balaji sb thanks,I have this idea before it seems works ,I will write it later

Comment: @Balaji sb can you provide a bit more idea,I don't know how to preceed? Using mollifier?

Comment: For a fixed $\epsilon$ (see section 2.4 or page 19 in the link i gave), we can prove the result as the function is smooth now. After that try letting $\epsilon$ to $0$. The issue will be that the convergence of $u^\epsilon$ to $u$ will be w.r.t $W_{loc}^{k,p}$. You need then prove the convergnce in $W^{k,p}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u_k'$ is bounded in $L^p$, so identifying $L^p = (L^q)^*$ it has a subsequence  converging weak-* to some $v \in L^p$.  Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c(I)$.  Then $\phi' \in L^q$ and so $\int_I u_{k_j}' \phi\,dx \to \int_I v \phi\,dx$.  On the other hand
$$ \int_I u_{k_j}' \phi\,dx =  - \int_I u_{k_j} \phi'\,dx \to -\int_I u \phi'\,dx$$
so $\int_I v \phi\,dx = -\int_I u \phi'\,dx$ for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(I)$, which shows that $u' = v$.

Comment: @Balajisb: The definition of weak-* convergence is that there is a single $v$ such that for all $\psi \in L^q$ we have $\int u_{k_j}' \psi \to \int v \psi$.  I don't need for the convergence to be uniform in $\psi$.

Comment: thanks .above arguement holds for $1<p\le \infty$ correct.If in particular $p \ne \infty$,then the weak star limit is the same as weak limit correct?

Comment: @yili: That's right.  For $1 < p < \infty$, $L^p$ is reflexive.